# How can I create a distinct list of javascript objects, when I need a compound key to make it distinct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, distinct-values

Yes, there are several posts about creating distinct lists in several languages, but I'm not seeing anything about using a compound or composite key.

I have an array of objects (contacts) with duplicates, that I need to make an array of distinct values from, with the key being *the composite of* the email, name, and phone fields. The objects look like this:

```
{
    name: "Name",
    email: "email@example.com",
    phone: "5551212",
    organization: "BigCompany",
    title: "CEO"
}
```

I can create a distinct list using map.has(), based on email only:

```
const distinct = [];
const map = new Map();
for (const item of contacts) {
    if(!map.has(item.email)){
        map.set(item.email, true); // set any value, but add an entry to the Map
        distinct.push(item);
    }
}
```

...but I need distinct array elements for each contact with the same email, but a different phone, or same phone, but different email, etc. Reading through the documentation on `map.has()`, I'm not seeing anything about the key parameter being a complex data structure (multiple fields, in this case). Is there some better tool, or am I just missing that section of the documentation?

Comment: you could combine a key with email and phone, but whot for? if the user changes the phone number, the key changes and that violates the idea of a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a JSON string to use as a key, like this:

```
const distinct = [];
const map = new Map();
for (const item of contacts) {
    const {name, email, phone} = item;
    const key = JSON.stringify({name, email, phone});
    if(!map.has(key){
        map.set(key, true);
        distinct.push(item);
    }
}
```

Since `JSON.stringify` ([spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-json.stringify) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) is required to follow ES2015's property order (which many operations aren't), you know that if you create the objects in the same way every time and all of the enumerable properties are "own" properties, the resulting JSON string will be the same for objects with the same `name`, `email`, and `phone` property values (and different if they're different). (That "create the objects in the same way every time" is important, the objects `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` result in **different** JSON strings.)

---

Side note: If you're just using `map.has` and `map.set(key, true)`, a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) would probably make more sense:

```
const distinct = [];
const set = new Set();
for (const item of contacts) {
    const {name, email, phone} = item;
    const key = JSON.stringify({name, email, phone});
    if(!set.has(key){
        set.add(key);
        distinct.push(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to store your distinct contacts by creating your own compound key:

```
const contacts = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    email: "email@example.com",
    phone: "5551212",
    organization: "BigCompany",
    title: "CEO"
  },
  // ...
]

// Store distinct contacts.
const map = new Map()

contacts.forEach((c) => {
  /**
   * Any contact with the same name, email, and phone will
   * be considered a duplicate.
   */
  const key = `${c.name}::${c.email}::${c.phone}`
  map.set(key, c)
})
```

Now your map is a container of items `{ key => contact }`.

To get a list of distinct contacts, use:

```
const list = Array.from(map.values())

// Use spread syntax to accoplish the same thing.
const list2 = [...map.values()]
```

Note: using the delimiter `::` can be considered unsafe if name, email, or phone number might contain that substring. Whichever delimiter you use, you should make sure you disallow it from input on those fields if possible, and/or make it such that the likelihood of it occurring in the input is highly improbable:

```
const delim = '__:DELIM:__'
const key = `${c.name}${delim}${c.email}${delim}${c.phone}`
```

Even still, there is no 100% guarantee that the delimiter won't occur in a field such as `name` unless you perform input validation on that field.

EDIT: On examination of T.J. Crowder's JSON key, using that method to generate your key would provide a good guarantee of no substring issues:

```
const key = JSON.stringify({name, email, phone});
map.set(key, c)
```

Comment: This makes the assumption that the attributes won't contain `::`, which generally speaking isn't that safe an assumption to make. That's why I used JSON.

Comment: Fair enough @T.J.Crowder, but any delimiter can be used, and `::` is unlikely to be part of any name, email, or phone number. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I think your JSON key is a great solution.